# MacOS Playground: How can change the background color?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift-playground

I'm trying to change the background color of main view:

```
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : NSViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let nibFile = NSNib.Name("MyView")
        var topLevelObjects : NSArray?
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(
            nibFile, owner:nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)
        let views = (topLevelObjects as! Array<Any>).filter { $0 is NSView }
        self.view = views[0] as! NSView
        self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

But the view doesn't change the color:

[image]

Also where the "Hello world" label is coming from?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Is the "Hello world!" in the nib? Is `self.view.layer` `nil`?

Comment: Where is the nib in the playground ?

Comment: Menu View->Navigators->Show Project Navigator. The xib is in the Resources folder.

Comment: @Willeke, thank you. I really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set your view wantsLayer property to true

```
let view = views[0] as! NSView
view.wantsLayer = true
view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know where is the "hello world" label is located?

Comment: you need to open your playground resources, click MyView.xib https://www.dropbox.com/s/9un7km2leby0q9q/MyView_xib.png?dl=1